# Which variables should be set as the properties of a class in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php

class oopClass{

    function __construct($editingtext, $searchfor, $replacewith){

        if(!empty($editingtext) && !empty($searchfor) && !empty($replacewith)){

           $editingtext = str_replace($searchfor,$replacewith,$editingtext);

           echo $editingtext;

        }else{

          echo 'All Fields Are Required.';

        }
    }
}

//closing php
```

The code is working , but as there is no properties of the class are set which is a bad practice, which variables of this code should be set as a class property and why?

Comment: it all depends on what the class is supposed to represent...

Comment: Why is not using properties bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily bad practice if the above code is ALL you plan on doing with this code. If you needed to expand its functionality, I might imagine `$editingtext` could be a property.

```
class oopClass{

    private $editingtext;        

    function __construct($editingtext, $searchfor, $replacewith){

        $this->editingtext = $editingtext;                

        if(!empty($this->editingtext) && !empty($searchfor) && !empty($replacewith)){

           $this->editingtext = str_replace($searchfor,$replacewith,$this->editingtext);

           echo $this->editingtext;

        }else{

          echo 'All Fields Are Required.';

        }
    }
}

//closing php
```

Comment: should't it be $this->editingtext = str_replace($searchfor,$replacewith,$this->editingtext);

Answer (score 0):

There are other things wrong with your code, and it is not the absence of properties. You are constructing an object and in the constructor you output the result. THAT is bad practice.

I'd fix it something like this:

```
class TextReplacer {
    var $search;
    var $replace;

    function __construct($s, $r) {
         $this->search = $s;
         $this->replace = $r;
    }

    function replace($text) {
        // your code, using the properties for search and replace, RETURNING the result
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

then call like:

```
$oo = new TextReplacer("bar", "baz");
echo $oo->replace("let's replace some bars in here");
```

In short:

1. Nothing wrong with not using properties, if your class is designed like that.
2. Please use useful class, method and variable names.
3. Don't do more than one thing in a method ("side effects").
4. Don't output the result, but return it. It is up to the user of the class to decide what happens to the results.
5. (most importantly): Think before you code.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by Don't do more than one thing in a method ("side effects"). ?

Comment: A method should do only what its signature or name suggests. In your case, a constructor should only construct. It shouldn't also do the replacement and echo stuff.